# Nextflow with Docker -- Problem with permission rights in WSL2

Tags: docker, wsl-2, nextflow

On WSL2 I am running the below Nextflow process via:

```
script.nf -with-docker memesuite/memesuite:latest
```

Outcome:

```
Command error:
  .command.sh: line 2: foo.txt: Permission denied
```

…but only when running on WSL2, not on a "pure" Linux machine and also not on macOS. If I access that container manually (`docker run -it`) in WSL2 I have to add `--user root` to be allowed to save anything to the WSL2 filesystem. What do I have to tell Nextflow to be able to publish to the WSL2 filesystem with the Docker profile?

The Nextflow process

```
#! /usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process A {

    publishDir launchDir, mode: 'move'

    output:
    path("foo.txt")

    script:
    """
    echo '123' > foo.txt
    """

}

workflow { A() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to play around with some of the [`docker` scope](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#config-docker) config options, but, to answer your immediate question, you might need something like this in your [nextflow.config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html):

```
docker {
    enabled = true
    runOptions = '--user root'
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
docker {
    enabled = true
    sudo = true
}
```

However, I wouldn't have expected you to need the above unless your container needs elevated privileges to run (which I don't think it does). I am not familiar with WSL2 at all, but I suspect you might just need to add your user to the `docker` group, creating it if necessary. Not sure if you have seen or followed the [post install](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) docs, but doing so might be helpful here:

> 1. Create the docker group.
>
> ```
> sudo groupadd docker
> ```
>
> 2. Add your user to the docker group.
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
> ```
>
> 3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
>
> > If testing on a virtual machine, it may be necessary to restart the
> > virtual machine for changes to take effect.
> >
> > On a desktop Linux environment such as X Windows, log out of your
> > session completely and then log back in.
> >
> > On Linux, you can also run the following command to activate the
> > changes to groups:
> >
> > ```
> > newgrp docker
> > ```
>
> 4. Verify that you can run docker commands without sudo.
>
> ```
> docker run hello-world
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I added the user to the group already, and strangely it happens only for some containers, not all, as most of the time jobs finish properly. Maybe add oddity with some containers and how they're build, in the meantime I'll use the runOption workaround.

Comment: @ATpoint No worries at all, thanks for the update! If only certain containers require root privileges for whatever reason, you might prefer setting the [containerOptions](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#containeroptions) directive rather than forcing all of them to run as root. For the problematic containers, I'd expect something like this to work: `containerOptions '--user root'`